# How to exclude constructors from being hit by Namespace wide aspects

Tags: postsharp, aop

I have just started using Postsharp as a way to do logging etc. on a project and have come across an issue I have yet to resolve.

In my project I have created my LogAttribute which correctly is logging out the information that I am trying to do e.g. Parameters going in and out methods. The only issue is that it is also doing this for all constructors as well, which I am not wanting to be logged.

Is there a way of excluding constructors from being logged out?

My GlobalAspects.cs looks similar to:

```
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: TraceAttribute(AttributeTargetTypes = "myNamespace.toLog.*", AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
```

My OnEntry, OnSuccess and On Exception methods in my attribute are all variants on:

```
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        output.Append("Entering: ");
        output.Append(this.methodName);

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Arguments.Count; i++)
        {
            output.Append("  Argument: " + i + " - ");
            output.Append(args.Arguments.GetArgument(i) ?? "null");
        }

        m_logger.Trace(output);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding the following to the attribute declaration it seems to have resolved the issue:

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
[Serializable]
public class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
}
```